# How to import generic messages into Gmail as emails?

Tags: gmail, import

I have some messages that I'd like to import to Gmail. The messages were never emails but are conversations from another service. Right now I have them in a .csv file with columns From,To,Date,Message

I would like the messages as emails in Gmail, for backup and so I can search them easily.

How can I import them into Gmail?

What format does it accept for upload?

Comment: Perhaps it will be necessary to import the messages into an email client such as Thunderbird, then upload them to Gmail using IMAP.

Comment: That's one alternative. I think that you could have problems with the date due to the way that it's handled by Gmail. I think that it's taken from the message headers.

Comment: What about uploading them to Google Drive?